# c++ polymorphism and passing subclasses around

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm getting my head around inheritance in c++, and trying to implement a basic setup in which
a base class has a) an abstract method `fire()` which subclasses must implement and b) a variable `someDouble` which subclasses inherit.

My current setup is below. This will not compile, as `getDerivedObject()` is attempting to return an abstract class. (Note I would prefer to keep `BaseClass` abstract if possible for safety.)

Another way I've tried is to have `AnotherClass` return a pointer to object instead - but that doesn't work either as `object`
will be deleted when it goes out of scope.

Is this the right overall approach? What can I return from `AnotherClass` that will allow me to access `getSomeDouble()` from the `BaseClass` and `fire()` from the `DerivedClass`?

```
class BaseClass{
public:
    virtual void fire() = 0;
    // Use a getter and setter as you can't make a variable virtual in c++
    virtual double getSomeDouble(){ return someDouble; }
    virtual void setSomeDouble(double d){ someDouble = d; }

private:
    double someDouble;
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass{
public:
    void fire(){ cout << "Derived class fired. Yay." << endl; }
};


class AnotherClass{
public:
    // Set up a DerivedClass object and set someDouble to 1
    BaseClass getDerivedObject(){ // currrently fails; can't return an abstract class
        DerivedClass object;
        object.setSomeDouble(1);
        return object; // I will later want this to return vector<BaseClass> or similar
    };
};


int main()
{
    AnotherClass t;
    BaseClass o = t.getDerivedObject();
    BaseClass * p = &o;

    cout << to_string( (*p).getSomeDouble() );
    (*p).fire();
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** I've tried using pointers like this, but of course the object is deleted when it leaves scope:

```
BaseClass * getDerivedObject(){
        DerivedClass object;
        object.setSomeDouble(1);
        BaseClass * p = &object;
        return p;
    };
```

Comment: Yes you have to work with pointers, when you want to use polymorphism. E,g, `vector<BaseClass>` wont work. You might want to take a look at the FactoryPattern (which is going a bit in a different direction but its related to your problem)

Comment: Basic technique: use `std::unique_ptr<BaseClass>`.  Advanced technique: use type erasure.

Comment: Thanks @tobi303. I've tried using pointers before but couldn't get it to work - I've just added some details of my attempt.

Comment: yes, thats because you have to use `new` if you want to prevent the object from getting destroyed (see e,g, answer of Yakk)

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense. I'm still getting my head around memory management too ;). Yakk and dwcanillas, thanks very much for the answers, both very enlightening - I'll leave it a little while in case anyone else wants to contribute, then choose an answer to accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `unique_ptr`s for pseudo-regular access to polymorphic objects.

```
template<class T>
using up=std::unique_ptr<T>;

// comes free in C++14
template<class T, class...Args>
up<T> make_unique( Args&&...args ) {
  return up<T>( new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...) );
}

up<BaseClass> getDerivedObject(){ // currrently fails; can't return an abstract class
    up<DerivedClass> object = make_unique<DerivedClass>();
    object->setSomeDouble(1);
    return object;
};
```

later:

```
up<BaseClass> o = t.getDerivedObject();

std::cout << to_string( o->getSomeDouble() );
o->fire();
```

this assumes C++11.  It is 2015, that seems safe.

The use of `up<T>` and `make_unique<T>` and `std::vector< up<T> >` mean that there is little to no need to call `new`.  Working with raw pointers is highly error prone, this avoids that, while still giving you dynamic polymorphism.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer Yakk. I'm getting a compiler error on `return object;`; "You cannot bind an lvalue to an rvalue reference". My IDE is also advising me that no conversion from `up<DerivedClass>` to `up<BaseClass>` exists. Can you advise on a fix?

Comment: @Giswok add `std::move`: `return std::move(object);` -- it was a defect in C++11 that the return-local-variable-implicitly-as-rvalue only works when the return type and the returned variable types match exactly.  In C++14 it is required to be supported.